# not able to create a new git repository using github plugin

Tags: android, github

I'm trying to upload my project into github but i'm facing an issue which that when i click on create git repository , it dosnt recognize my projects files like activitis , fragments , it does only upload the gradle folders , any solution and thank you for any help in advance

- This is a screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading the project to git using command line with this steps:

1. Go to your github account and create new repo
2. open Git bash in your project or make sure to change the current working directory to your project (git should be installed on your system).
3. Initialize the directory as a Git repository using : `git init -b main`
4. Add the files in your new repository using `git add .`
5. Commit the files that you've staged in your local repository using: `git commit -m "First commit"`
6. Go to your repo page on github and copy the remote repo URL (under Quick setup)
7. Go back to git bash and add remote repo URL
   `git remote add origin remote repository URL`
8. Finaly push the changes: `git push origin main`
   it may ask for credentials

Comment: I know that's good way to do it as well but i would like to know the reason behind that issue , cause i had android studio 4.0 before and it worked file , it shows all files proeprly , i had some issues and reinstalled my windows along with android studio 4.1.1  , now i'm facing the issue , and thank you for the answer

Comment: @takieddine i had many issues after upgrading android studio form v4.0 to version 4.1 so i had to delete android studio and all cached files and then download the latest version. i think this is the best solution to avoid many issues like the urs